# Tela de bloqueio lockscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

É possível criar uma **lockscreen** em JS+HTML+CSS com a mesma funcionalidade do bloqueio do *Windows*? 
Penso em fazer isso no sistema web que estou fazendo.

Comment: Não sei se é exatamente o que tu queres. Encontrei duas demos com código fonte. https://codepen.io/khadkamhn/pen/EVaJLy https://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-simple-screen-grey-effect-jquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Usando o método `setTimeout` do *JavaScript* você consegue programar para que o bloqueio de tela seja executado no tempo determinado, e também criei a função pra "reiniciar" o tempo caso o usuário esteja "ativo" no site, através dos métodos `onclick` e `onmousemove`.

Bem, fiz um exemplo usando *JavaScript*+*jQuery*, e também um com *JavaScript* puro:

*HTML*:

```
<div id="content">
AQUI ESTÁ SEU CONTEÚDO, AGUARDE 5 SEGUNDOS SEM MOVER O MOUSE E A TELA SERÁ TRAVADA.
</div>

<div id="lockscreen">
<div class="lock-msg">Insira sua senha para desbloquear a tela.</div>
<input class="lockscreen-password" type="password"></input>
<input type="submit" class="lockscreen-btn" value="DESBLOQUEAR"></input>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
#content {
position:absolute;
top:150px;
left:50px;
}
#lockscreen {
position:fixed;
z-index:999;
cursor:forbidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
color:white;
display:none;
}
.lock-msg{
position:relative;
display:table;
margin:auto;
top:300px;
}
.lockscreen-password{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
display:table;
margin:auto;
top:350px;
}
.lockscreen-btn{
position:relative;
display:table;
margin:auto;
top:380px;
}
```

*JavaScript* + *jQuery*

```
locked = false;
    function lockScreen() {
        /*1000 ms = 1 seg*/
        var timeout = 5000
        if (locked == true) {
            clearTimeout(lockscreen);
        }
        else {
            lockscreen = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#lockscreen').show();
                locked = true;
                clearTimeout(lockscreen);
            }, timeout);
        }
    }
    $(document).click(function(){
        clearTimeout(lockscreen);
        lockScreen();
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(){
        clearTimeout(lockscreen);
        lockScreen();
    });

lockScreen();
    $('.lockscreen-btn').click(function(){
    var lck_senha = $('.lockscreen-password').val();
        if (lck_senha == "swordfish") {
            locked = false;
            $('.lockscreen-password').val("");
            $('#lockscreen').hide();
        }
    });
```

Puro *JavaScript*:

```
locked = false;
function lockScreen() {
    if (locked == true) {
        clearTimeout(lockscreen);
    }
    else {
        lockscreen = setTimeout(function(){
        triggerToggle = document.getElementById("lockscreen");
        triggerToggle.style.display = 'initial';
        locked = true;
        clearTimeout(lockscreen);
        }, 5000);
    }
}
document.onclick = triggerLockByClick;
function triggerLockByClick() {
    clearTimeout(lockscreen);
    lockScreen();
}
document.onmousemove = triggerLockByMove;
function triggerLockByMove() {
    clearTimeout(lockscreen);
    lockScreen();
};
document.querySelector('.lockscreen-btn').onclick = unlock;
function unlock() {
    lck_senha = document.getElementsByClassName('lockscreen-password')[0].value;
    if (lck_senha == "swordfish") {
        document.getElementsByClassName('lockscreen-password').value = "";
        triggerToggle.style.display = 'none';
        locked = false;
    }       
}
lockScreen();
```

Caso queira ver um exemplo:
[Exemplo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Knautiluz/2yjj71q7/51/)

**A senha é *swordfish***

Claro que você teria que criar algum tipo de validação server-side para que o usuário não conseguisse editar pelo console. Eu acho que o mais simples seria fazer o LogOut do usuário depois do tempo pré-determinado.