# Função para deslogar através da inatividade

Tags: php

Bom, no meu projeto quando o usuário faz o login o sistema executa uma função que cria uma session com email dele para autentica-lo durante o site:

Função:

```
function logaUsuario($email) {
     $_SESSION["usuario_logado"] = $email;
}
```

Funções que verificam se o usuário está logado:

```
function usuarioEstaLogado() {
return isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"]);
}

function verificaUsuario() {
    if(!usuarioEstaLogado()) {

       header("Location: login.php");
       die();
    }
}
```

porém eu preciso fazer com que após alguns minutos de inatividade o sistema deslogue o usuário mas mantenha o email salvo. Qual seria a melhor forma de "deslogar" o usuário porém continuar com seu email armazenado?

Comment: Vc quer deslogar o usuário e manter a SESSION com o e-mail?

Comment: Você está condicionando a SESSION onde foi armazenada o e-mail do usuário ao fato de ele estar logado, certo?

Comment: @DavidSamm Sim, sim

Comment: Sei. Mas o que vc quer fazer com o e-mail do usuário depois que ele for deslogado. Pq quando a SESSION expira, não tem como recuperá-la. Ela vai ficar vazia.

Comment: Relacionado: [Tela de Bloqueio Lockscreen](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206053/tela-de-bloqueio-lockscreen/206331#206331)

Comment: você terá que armazenar o email em algum lugar... podes informar o pq de manter o email? saber pode ajudar a traçar uma estratégia.

Comment: Quase oque o @Knautiluz disse pretendo fazer uma "Tela de descanso" onde por exemplo caso o usuário fique inativo por x minutos estando com o site aberto ou não ele armazene o email, como se fosse um Cookie, porém não acho que o cookie seria seguro o suficiente

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer igual o do facebook que mostra a foto de perfil do usuário ao invés de ter de digitar o email e a senha o usuário só precisaria digitar a senha para autenticar

Comment: Usando a função que respondi abaixo, você pode verificar depois se $_SESSION['usuario_logado'] existe e se contém email, ai você consegue fazer igual o facebook, apenas pedir a senha.

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Se a questão é segurança, armazenar somente o email na máquina atual em que o usuário está acessando eu acho que não é grande problema de segurança.

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Digamos que estou em uma lanhouse. É comum eu entrar em um site onde alguém já acessou antes e me deparar com o email  de outro usuário. Basta eu clicar "não sou fulano" ou tentar adivinhar a senha do "fulano", coisa que ninguem irá se dar o trabalho de fazer.

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Você pode armazenar o email do usuário numa localStorage quando ele logar, e quando a SESSION dele expirar, vc chama essa localStorage APENAS pra pegar o email dele para um novo login, devendo ele apenas digitar a senha.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkAtividade() {
    if(time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'] > 900) { // Subtrai timestamp atual com o armazenado em SESSION['timestamp']
        echo"<script>alert('Deslogado por inatividade!');</script>";
        unset($_SESSION['timestamp']);
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
        header("Location: " . login.php); // Redireciona para a pagina login.php
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time(); // Atualiza timestamp
    }
}
```

**Altere suas funções:**

```
function logaUsuario($email) {
    $_SESSION["usuario_logado"] = $email;
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
}

function usuarioEstaLogado() {
    return isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]);
}
```

Comment: Na função de checar o "900" seria oque? segundos ou ms?

Comment: Coloquei a função e toda vez que tento logar o sistema ja me desloga

Comment: os 900 é em segundos

Comment: atualize a função **logaUsuario** como eu deixei agora na resposta